# String comparison in dotnet framework 4

Tags: visual-studio, string, .net-4.0, comparison, performance

I will explain my problem(excuse my bad English), I have a .NET exe in which every milliseconds of processing is very important.

This program does lots of string comparison (most of it is `string1.IndexOf(string2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`).

When i switch to framework 4, my program time is twice than before.

I searched for explanation and I found that the function `IndexOf(s, OrdinalIgnoreCase)` is much slower in framework 4 (I did test with a simple console application and in a loop the time was 30ms in 3.5 and 210ms in 4.0 ???). But the comparison in current culture is quicker in framework 4 than 3.5.

Here it's a sample of code I use :

```
int iMax = 100000;
String str  = "Mozilla/5.0+(Windows;+U;+Windows+NT+5.1;+fr;+rv:1.9.0.1)+Gecko/2008070208+Firefox/3.0.1";
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
StringComparison s = StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase;
for(int i = 1;i<iMax;i++)
{
    str.IndexOf("windows", s);
}
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
Console.Read();
```

My questions are :

1. Has anyone noticed the same problem?
2. Someone have an explanation on this change?
3. Is there a solution to bypass the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Are your string parameters based on char types or string types?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok i have a response of one of my question.

With reflector i can see the difference between framework 2 and 4 and that explain my perforamnce issue.

```
    public int IndexOf(string value, int startIndex, int count, StringComparison comparisonType)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
    }
    if ((startIndex < 0) || (startIndex > this.Length))
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("startIndex", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_Index"));
    }
    if ((count < 0) || (startIndex > (this.Length - count)))
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("count", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_Count"));
    }
    switch (comparisonType)
    {
        case StringComparison.CurrentCulture:
            return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.CompareInfo.IndexOf(this, value, startIndex, count, CompareOptions.None);

        case StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase:
            return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.CompareInfo.IndexOf(this, value, startIndex, count, CompareOptions.IgnoreCase);

        case StringComparison.InvariantCulture:
            return CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.CompareInfo.IndexOf(this, value, startIndex, count, CompareOptions.None);

        case StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase:
            return CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.CompareInfo.IndexOf(this, value, startIndex, count, CompareOptions.IgnoreCase);

        case StringComparison.Ordinal:
            return CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.CompareInfo.IndexOf(this, value, startIndex, count, CompareOptions.Ordinal);

        case StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase:
            return TextInfo.IndexOfStringOrdinalIgnoreCase(this, value, startIndex, count);
    }
    throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("NotSupported_StringComparison"), "comparisonType");
}
```

This is the base code of function IndexOf of the 2 framework (no difference between 4 and 2)

But in the function TextInfo.IndexOfStringOrdinalIgnoreCase there are differences :

Framework 2 :

```
    internal static unsafe int IndexOfStringOrdinalIgnoreCase(string source, string value, int startIndex, int count)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    }
    return nativeIndexOfStringOrdinalIgnoreCase(InvariantNativeTextInfo, source, value, startIndex, count);
}
```

Framework 4 :

```
    internal static int IndexOfStringOrdinalIgnoreCase(string source, string value, int startIndex, int count)
{
    if ((source.Length == 0) && (value.Length == 0))
    {
        return 0;
    }
    int num = startIndex + count;
    int num2 = num - value.Length;
    while (startIndex <= num2)
    {
        if (CompareOrdinalIgnoreCaseEx(source, startIndex, value, 0, value.Length, value.Length) == 0)
        {
            return startIndex;
        }
        startIndex++;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

The main algorithm has changed in framework 2 the call is a nativeDll that has been removed of framework 4.
Its good to know

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue in .NET 4.

[Here is the MS Connect report](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/699078/performance-of-string-indexof-string-stringcomparison-ordinalignorecase-is-worse-than-invariantcultureignorecase).

Answer (score 0):

I cannot answer on your specific .NET 4 speed issue.

However you'd probably gain much more speed by **improving your algo**. Check out the [Rabin-Karp string search algo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_string_search_algorithm).

Comment: Yes i can use another algo but i want to know why framework 4 is slower than framework 2. I check out the Rabin-Karp thanks

Comment: I cant tell that from some points it has been said to be faster. May be it's slower on others.